# FBX import crashing UE4

Tags: maya, unreal-engine4, fbx

Exporting from Maya to UE4 is causing the UE Editor to crash with no explanation. The submit error report dialog appears but there is no useful information available.

I have tried changing the FBX Version as some posts suggest, however, this does not seem to help.

How can I go about addressing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When exporting make sure the base model is in editable mesh and not editable poly and make sure the FBX exporter is set to ASCII not Binary.

This happened to me on 3ds Max, I am not a maya user

Comment: Sorted, I've been trying for weeks to fix that!

Comment: Thanks mate for accepting this, was my first answer around here. Be sure to submit this as a bug report to ue4 community

Answer (score 0):

i had recently come across with the same crash... while importing from fbx

from mixamo and maya what worked for me was....while exporting fbx i had done the resetting of fbx preset to autodesk media and entertainment and switched off the smoothmesh option and enabled the Triangulate..

please do delete the unused nodes before exporting and keep no group nodes above the mesh or skeleton...

hope that helps those encounter similar in their workflow

as i was doing the following test projects this error occurred and crashed...

Project link1 : https://youtu.be/OsvZ1cpBBf0

Project Link 2: https://youtu.be/sXMrTkPiVEM

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ9Pv.jpg)